# Can't play mp4 in Cocoa-Touch App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to play an `mp4` after detecting a signal in the audio jack. 
The video is playing once, after a delay of 1 sec which i dont want, and then application is freezing and i get this warning on the debugger: (only on the iphone, its working on simulation)

```
(8F190)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/H264H4.videodecoder (file not found).
(8F190)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH4.videodecoder (file not found).
```

my code for the video is this :

```
//play video1
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample1" ofType:@"mp4"]]; 
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
        moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession=NO;
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault; 
        [moviePlayer setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer play];
```

I couldnt find anything on this warning on the net.

I have tried any kind of video encoding,according to the Apple docs.
We just cant play movies, does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

thanks .

Comment: Xcode cant play anything — it is just an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you run that code twice, the video won't play the second time, because you are creating a second MPMoviePlayerController and a second view, and only one MPMoviePlayerController view in your app can play video. So it works the first time but not the second time. You should be retaining your MPMovieVideoController in a property so that you can remove its view and release the MPMovieVideoController before trying to make a new one.

Comment: thanks, i have added this : @property(nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;  can you direct me on how to play the movie now ?

Comment: also i see a black screen between 2 times i play a video. can anybody please help me with playing a video normally ? the goal is to play the videos in a way that it seems like animation,with no delays and no black screen in between.  i know its just something simple that i am doing wrong here , and i dont know what . please help me with that ..

Comment: See the p659moviePlayer example from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples - part of what it's trying to show you is how to get rid of one video player so you can use another.